# Changing number of columns on wordpress blog page

Tags: wordpress

This is a real rookie question. Apologies in advance.

I am looking to change the following blog page from 3 columns to 2 columns.

https://www.marriedin.co.uk/wedding-hacks

I have been viewing source in the inspector in Chrome. My thinking was that I could simply edit the following:

```
<div class="blog-archive blog-archive--grid" data-columns="2">
```

This may not work but this is what I planned to try. My problem is that I do not know which file this would be in when I access the site through an SFTP client. Is there any way to work this out from the inspector?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there may be a simple way in your Theme Options to change this to two columns but in case it isn't you could edit the template files. Your blog template is most likely under archive.php or index.php in your theme folder.. although you should have a look at [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) if you should have trouble locating the file to edit.

Somewhere in the blog template file these divs are being generated which you can see when you inspect your site.

```
  <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
```

These are bootstrap elements that make 3 columns. Take a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/) if you are not familiar with bootstrap.

To make it 2 columns like you want, change the "col-md-4" classes to "col-md-6".

That should do the trick, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I’ve hunted through the files in the theme folder but have been unable to find it. I contacted the theme developer who said that the index.php file controls the blog layout but I can’t find it in there. I’m wondering if it references another file?